# Excel - Pick Top 3 Choices

Tags: microsoft-excel

I exported a Qualtrics survey which had users rank 6 options. I want to then take their top 3 options and list them in the row.

Example:

```
Choice A    Choice B    Choice C    Choice D    Choice E    Choice F    1 2 3
1           5           3           4           2           6           A E C
```

Basically like this ^. I was thinking that I needed to use HLOOKUP or VLOOKUP or something, but I couldn't figure out how. I was thinking just using some equation and then I could fill the series down my list of 300 entries.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: You can use hlookup() but the numbers would have to be in the top row, and the choices in the 2nd row.

Are you going to have a full table with lots of rows of answers

Comment: The spreadsheet is set up to have each choice as a column header and then the # that they ranked that choice in the row.

Comment: Or can I do if statements where I say if ChoiceA = 1, display A, if not, see if choice B = 1 and then display B... how do I make a nested if like that though?

Comment: Do you need the top 3 choices all in the same cell? If so, separated by what?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
=IF($H2=1,$H$1,IF($I2=1,$I$1,IF($J2=1,$J$1,IF($K2=1,$K$1,IF($L2=1,$L$1,IF($M2=1,$M$1))))))
```

(assuming "Choice A" was in H1 and "1" was in H2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: 
Everything is in the same location you described in your answer; the 1, 2, and 3 headings are in N1, O1, and P1; and the user data is in successive rows.  Enter this formula in N2, then copy it to O2 and P2.  Then you can copy the three display cells down for all user rows:

```
    =OFFSET($H$1,0,MATCH(N$1,$H2:$M2,0)-1,1)
```

This selects the choice name that is in the same column as the rank defined by the column heading of the display item.